# Testing Pagination of Facebook Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, testing

I need to test that I can fetch subsequent pages of reviews from facebooks graph API.

The issue I have is that an account can only review a page once, and pagination doesn't kick in til there are **over 100** reviews.

Do I really need to create 101 user accounts and have each one of them manually submit a review, just so I can be sure that when real companies use the software I'll be able to fetch the paginated results correctly?

Is there an alternative?

Comment: Just set a lower limit in your initial request …

Comment: @CBroe That works a treat. Fancy fleshing it out as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The issue I have is that an account can only review a page once, and pagination doesn't kick in til there are **over 100** reviews.

That’s just the default limit for that endpoint - but you can specify a different limit in your initial query (simply via the parameter of the same name, `/page/ratings?limit=3`)

The `prev`/`next` links generated by the API then also use that limit value.

That way, you should be able to test pagination on smaller datasets as well.